# Why can't a polynomial of degree $n$ have less than $n$ (complex) roots, counted with multiplicity?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, proof-explanation

According to the fundamental theorem of algebra, any polynomial of degree $n$ has exactly $n$ (complex) roots counted with multiplicity)

My text book explains that an $n$ degree polynomial can have, at most, $n$ roots as follows:

> If a $n$ degree polynomial had roots [ $α_1,α_2,...α_{n+1}$], then, by the factor theorem, each of $(x-α_1),(x-α_2)...(x-α_{n+1})$ must be a factor of P(x), and so must be their product $$\Rightarrow P(x)=(x-\alpha_1)(x-\alpha_2)...(x-\alpha_{n+1})\ \cdot\ Q(x)\quad \text{where Q(x) is another polynomial}$$
> But that would mean that the degree of the right is at least $n+1$, so P(x) cannot be an $n$ degree polynomial.

To me, this only proves that if a polynomial has $n$ roots, it must be at least $n$ degree. What I don't understand is how this implies that there can't be an $n$ degree polynomial with less than $n$ roots (even when counted with multiplicity).

Following the same logic used in the text book, if there is a polynomial of degree $n$ with $m<n$ **known** roots, P(x) can be expressed as $$P(x)=(x-\alpha_1)(x-\alpha_2)...(x-\alpha_{m})\ \cdot\ Q(x)\quad \text{where Q(x) is a polynomial of degree}\ (n-m)$$

How do you we know that Q(x) must also have $(n-m)$ roots ? I feel like this is a very stupid and obvious question, but I can't really explain why for some reason?

Comment: The important part of the theorem is that complex polynomials of degree at least $1$ have roots. So, if $Q(x)$ has degree $n - m > 0$, then it too must have roots.

Comment: The textbook isn't proving the fundamental theorem of algebra right there (if it's ever doing it at all). The fact that $\deg(pq)=\deg p+\deg q$ is not quite related to the fundamental theorem of algebra or to the number of roots, but it just follows from more basic facts on polynomial multiplication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> To me, this only proves that if a polynomial has n roots, it must be at least n degree.

Correct.

> What I don't understand is how this implies that there can't be an n degree polynomial with less than n roots (even when counted with multiplicity).

It doesn't.

---

As other people have stated, the hard part is knowing that every nonconstant polynomial has *at least one* root, because then we can just keep factoring out roots until we get down to a constant.

However, showing that a non-constant polynomial has at least one root is *not* an elementary result, and cannot be proven without using at least a little calculus.  Moreover, the proofs that just use a little bit of calculus are very unenlightening; they're basically the sort of thing you can only come up with when you already know the answer.  To *really* understand the fundamental theorem of algebra you need to know some complex analysis, which is a course you'd typically take after completing an entire college calculus sequence and maybe a few more courses on top of that.

Since it sounds like your book is not at this level, it sounds like they're telling you that the fundamental theorem of algebra is true to allow you to see what it's useful for, but they're definitely not proving it.

(To give you a preview, the cleanest proof works by taking the complex plane, wrapping it up into a sphere and gluing it together by sticking on a point at infinity, and then noticing that your polynomial has a "pole of degree $n$" at this point and cannot be infinite anywhere else.  It follows that it has to have $n$ zeroes, counted with multiplicity, in order to "balance out" how quickly it goes to infinity.)

Comment: I haven't read it, but [here is a paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1504.05609) purporting to have a proof of the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra without any analysis.

Comment: @TheoBendit: Did you read the abstract?  Without reading the paper, it sounds like they're just doing analysis but doing it with infinitesimals and calling that "algebra" by working over the hyperreals.  Anyway, the fundamental theorem of algebra only applies to real-closed fields, and you can't even *define* any real-closed field without using some kind of analysis, which is why I say you can't prove the theorem without using some analysis.

Comment: I don't like the last paragraph because it doesn't seem to convey anything. The best proof is probably via [Rouche's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%27s_theorem) since it is most intuitive. Incidentally, the field theory proof requires real analysis only in the claim that every non-constant real cubic has a real root, though I dislike this proof.

Answer (score 3):

We would know by the fundamental theorem of algebra, applied to $Q$.

The form I know the FTA only says "at least one root", and then "exactly $n$ roots" is a corollary. Regardless, once you know any non-constant complex polynomial has at least one root, the proof that the number of roots is exactly the degree follows, for instance, by induction on the degree.

For a first-degree polynomial, it is obvious they have exactly a single root. (If you're not being too picky, non-zero constant polynomials could also serve as a base case here, but then the induction step for degree $1$ and for degree greater than $1$ would have to be different anyways. So degree one is the base case I choose.)

Fix some $k>1$, and assume that any polynomial of degree less than $k$ has exactly as many roots as its degree. For any polynomial $Q_k$ of degree $k$, the FTA tells us that it has at least one root $a$, so we get $Q_k(x) = (x-a)Q_{k-1}(x)$ for some polynomial $Q_{k-1}$ of degree $k-1$. But that means by the induction hypothesis that $Q_{k-1}$ has exactly $k-1$ roots, and multiplying by $(x-a)$ adds exactly one root. So $Q_k$ has exactly $k$ roots.

Comment: I was actually trying to prove ( to some extent at least) the FTA through this but other answer shows that this isn't an elementary result at all

Comment: @OVERWOOTCH It definitely isn't an elementary result. There are elegant proofs out there once you know enough complex analysis to, say, have a good feel for how winding numbers work. But it definitely sounds like that comes later.